# Fantasy/Horror novella about a young boy travelling on a ship and finding a giant eye in a volcano crater

Tags: story-identification, horror, novella

I read the novella about 5-6 years ago, but I do not know how old it is. I am also not sure, if it was written in German or English. In any case, it was quite short, maybe 150 pages and I had to order it directly from the publisher instead of Amazon e.g.

The story was about a boy who worked on a ship as an assistant to the cook. During the journey the ship probably "switched dimensions". In fact, I know quite less of the start and the middle of the book. The crew descended slowly in to madness, maybe there was cannibalism.

At the end however - and I am very sure about this - the boy and the cook find a volcano and ascend it. On the way up they see all sorts of petrified humans. As they reach the rim they see a gigantic eye which fills the complete volcano. In horror they try to flee only to become petrified themselves, but staying alive within and forced to contemplate the eye for eternity.

Comment: It sounds Lovecraftian, though I don't recall a Lovecraft story along those lines. One of his imitators perhaps? Clark Ashton Smith or August Derleth?

Comment: @JohnRennie, it had a pretty Lovecraftian feel, but it was definitely not by him. Probably, also not be the other authors you mentioned. I am going to have a closer look at their bibliography.

Comment: I have a pretty complete collection of Ashton Smith's and Derleth's work and I can't find anything that matches in them. The trouble is that lots of authors have written Lovecraft inspired stories, including recent authors like Brian Lumley (I've checked his books as well).

Comment: @JohnRennie thanks for checking it!